# how to change homepath variable in windows 10 to see directory I want very first in cmd

Tags: cmd, windows-10, settings

It seems very simple but I couldn't fine a solution for this.

If I open command prompt in Window, It shows directory root like C:\Users\username very first. I wanted to change this because it is not convenient that I need to move to a directory I work every time when I open cmd.

Well,
I tried SET HOMEPATH \Users\username\what I want to go. It kept showing HOMEPATH=\Users\username on cmd screen. I twisted it like opening cmd as administrator and typing SETX HOMEPATH, HOME... trying other stuffs I searched.

but still, I couldn't find way to set a directory root I want to see very first in cmd.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- For a concrete change, create a shortcut to open `cmd` with the desired folder as the default active directory.
- For a general change, include in the registry, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` a new `REG_SZ` value called `AutoRun` and set its value to `cd /d "c:\folder\where\I\work"`. Any `cmd` instance created without the `/D` switch will execute this code.
- Or you can create the same value under the registry, but with a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type and use as value something like `cd /D "%MY_HOME_PATH%"`, and, of course, ensure the `MY_HOME_PATH` variable is properly defined before starting the `cmd` instance.

Comment: Thank for answer. So There is not way to set to show directory which I want to see at very first when I hit cmd. I can set only shortcut to move directory which I want to go directly. right?

Comment: @Jayground, As pointed, you can change the indicated registry entry. See `cmd /?`, it is a documented way of doing it.